# How to parse arguments in python 2.6 with prefix option as -f file.xml

Tags: python, parsing, command-line-arguments, python-2.6

I would like to parse arguments passed from the command line with the prefix option as such :

`python myApp.y -f file.xml`

I am using python 2.6.6 so I cannot use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse).

And I would like to make it a bit more generic and scalable than

```
arg1 = sys.argv[1]
arg2 = sys.argv[2]
```

And then use `if`s to check the values and whether they have been provided.

Comment: See if getopt is installed.

Comment: @jeffmurphy -- [getopt](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html) is part of the python standard library, but I don't really see any good reason to use it when argparse and optparse are both significantly easier to use ...

Comment: @mgilson because it answers the OPs question and argparse, according to the OP, doesnt.

Comment: @jeffmurphy -- but `optparse` *does* (and is still significantly better than `getopt`).

Comment: @mgilson and is deprecated as bonus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html), but `argparse` [is available](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse) and can easily be installed on python 2.6.

Here's how you'd do it with argparse:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f','--filename',action='store',help='file!')
namespace = parser.parse_args()
print namespace.filename
```

---

Or with optparse:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-f", "--filename", dest="filename",help="file!")
options, args = parser.parse_args()
print options.filename
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for those examples!

Comment: @Patryk -- The second one was taken pretty much straight from the optparse docs as I'm not as familiar with that library.  I really do recommend `argparse`.  There's a reason they deprecated `optparse` in favor of `argparse` (mainly that `argparse` is pretty awesome) :-)

Comment: I know that but for my needs this is enough and I work on preconfigured machines so that it is problematic to install module on all of them.

Comment: @Patryk -- Fair enough, and that's why I gave both as options in my answer.